# Null Pointer Exception textview

Tags: java, android

There is a Null Pointer Exception in setText (java.lang.CharSquence) on a null object reference, idk why? The textview tv is in another activity, maybe thats the point?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class);
EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.liczba);
EditText edittext2 = findViewById(R.id.liczba2);
int wpis2 = Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().toString());
int wpis = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
int suma  = wpis + wpis2;
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(suma));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: IMO `TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);` the reference tv is null.

Comment: I can't see the entire code, but did you instantiate the object `tv`?

Comment: can you post complete activity code

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you will get a NullPointerException if you try to access an Object from findViewById, when it's not found.

I assume, you try to populate a TextField on the Activitys View you try to redirect to? If this is the case, you can add additional objects to the intent, which will be read out from the second Activity.

On the first Activity try:

```
intent.putExtra("myText", String.valueOf(suma));
startActivity(intent);
```

And on the second Activitys onCreate try:

```
Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();

if (incomingIntent.hasExtra("myText")) {
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);
    tv.setText(incomingIntent.getStringExtra("myText");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Null Pointer Exception in setText (java.lang.CharSquence) on a null object reference**

```
   TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);
   tv.setText(String.valueOf(suma));
```

As the exception and above codes indicates that tv can't be found in your rootview tree . so you must add the TextView id is "result" to this activity's contentView(layout xml file).

Answer (score 0):

you can't access direct to the textView of other activity you have to pass intent when you start activity then when activity create then find TextView by id and then getIntent that you pass from previous activity and set it into text View.

First of all when you create activity pass value in intent

```
    EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.liczba);
    EditText edittext2 = findViewById(R.id.liczba2);
    int wpis2 = Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().toString());
    int wpis = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
    int suma  = wpis + wpis2;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultActivit.class);
    intent.putExtra("suma", suma);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and then in DisplayResultActivit

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.result);
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    int suma = getIntent().getIntExtra("suma",0);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(suma));
}
```